# Form1_FormClosing method 'never used', settings do not save

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm saving the location of my application but it does not want to keep the value. What happens in the code now is that the `_FormClosing` is dimmed and "it is never used". Is there anybody that can see where I go wrong with this code below?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Settings.Default.WindowLocation != null)
            this.Location = Settings.Default.WindowLocation;

        this.txtInput60.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(CheckEnterKeyPress);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.WindowLocation = this.Location;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void CheckEnterKeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            decimal minutes;
            decimal.TryParse(txtInput60.Text, out minutes);

            if (minutes > 0)
            {
                var total = (int) (minutes/60*100);
                txtOutput100.Text = total.ToString();
                Clipboard.SetText(total.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

In my application properties I am setting the WindowLocation with  WindowLocation, system.draw.point, user, 0;0

Comment: Please change the title into something more appropriate and descriptive. The current title is too generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the event FormClosing to the method Form1_FormClosing.

This can be done in code of the Form_Load method:

```
this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
```

Or by [setting the event in the designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwsdtbk%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Change the type of the method parameter from FormClosedEventArgs to FormClosingEventArgs:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default.WindowLocation = this.Location;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: this does not work. it gives error on the form1_formclosing

No overload for 'Form1_FormClosing' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler'

Comment: Change the type of the method parameter from FormClosedEventArgs to FormClosingEventArgs

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your `Form1_FormClosing` event is no longer hooked up to the `FormClosing` event of the form. You can check this by going to the properties of the form at design-time and selecting events pane, looks like this:

[image: Properties Pane]

Make sure your `Form1_Closing` method is hooked up to the `FormClosing` event, if not, drop down the list and select it.

Answer (score 0):

Check in Form1 in Designer. Open the EventExplorer of Form1 and check the value for the Closing event. Maybe it is not attached to your method.

Answer (score 0):

Your designer is probably not attaching to the FormClosed event, try adding this in the constructor, just after `InitializeComponent();`

```
this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
```